# Finding a file for minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't find my Minecraft file in windows 10, I have tried to look in %AppData%, Roaming, Microsoft apps, etc. I have searched my computer a lot and it seems like the file doesn't exist for some reason, I know I own Minecraft 1.10 and all the things that come with it but the file won't show up.

Comment: Are you talking about regular Minecraft, where 1.10 came out years ago, or pocket edition? If it's the second one, your tag is wrong.

Comment: I think that because I use bedrock edition and not java edition that I can only have 1.10.

Comment: Ah, ok, I fixed your tag now. Next time, please read their descriptions to make sure you use the right ones. The situation of Minecraft tags on this site is a bit messy, but does follow rules.

Comment: I'm on PC. not PE

Comment: Yes, as I said, the tags here are a bit messy. Bedrock edition's original name was "pocket edition" and the tag names here haven't been updated in a long time. There's also a "minecraft-bedrock-edition" tag, I don't know if that's different.

Comment: yea, can we re-tag this question preferably, somehow? i'm still confused on the game version Andrew has

Answer (score 2):

The [Mojang site](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1480874-where-are-minecraft-files-stored-) has a list of all the locations to find your files, based on OS and version.

For the Java version:

> The remaining launcher files can be found by starting the launcher, logging in, going to "Launch options", choosing a launch configuration from the list ("Latest release" is the default) and clicking the little green arrow to the right of the "Game directory" option.

And the Bedrock Edition (Windows 10 Edition):

> Press Win+R, then type %appdata%.minecraft, then press Ok.

However, if something odd happened (like the directory changed for some reason) you can go to your menu, choose the Resource Pack, then click on "Open Resource Pack Folder". This should open up the relevant Minecraft directory. From here you should be able to navigate back up to where your world save is stored.

Comment: When I press Win+R and type it out it does the same thing as if I was trying to search it in the file, it says that windows can't find the file.  and when you say you want me to go to the menu and choose a resource pack, I assume you're talking about in Minecraft and in it, there is nothing that says "Open Resource Pack Folder".